# Is it possible to import/process advanced light attributes (IES) in WebGL?

Tags: animation, three.js, webgl, blender, lighting

IES (Illuminating Engineering Society) is a file format (.ies) that enhances lights in animation tools. It adds accurate falloff, dispersion, color temperature, spatial emission, brightness and stuff like that. It's an industrial standard to show how lighting products really look like. Many animation tools (Maya, Cinema4D, Blender etc.) are able to utilize this format.

Yet, I'm still searching for a way to import/use IES in WebGL frameworks. Using an animation tool (in my case Blender) to import and process .ies-files and finally export the project to a webgl-format seemed to be the most promising method to me. I tried out a couple of WebGL-Frameworks (three.js, x3dom, coppercube) and many more export formats/import-/converter scripts but none of it produced satisfying results. The processed results showed no lights, default lights or at best the same number of lights with no further attributes.

Does anybody by any chance know of a working combination of animation tool -> export function -> WebGL-framework or WebGL-ies-format-import that would do the trick?

Are there people with the same problem and longing for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe transfer *some* attributes from .ies files (color, intensity and such), but the Three.js renderer simply doesn't support the complex light properties .ies (like the shape of light) is meant to describe. So, even if you were able to import/export those properties, the default Three.js light system would not be able to render them properly.

Even if you implemented your own shaders and lights (you can do that in Three.js), it probably would still be prohibitively slow and/or inaccurate, as you probably need some raytracing/pathtracing -based approach for good enough results. WebGL approach to rendering in general, no matter what library or framework you use, is not very good fit for complex, accurate simulation of lights and shadows.

That being said, I would be highly interested in any solution, even a crude approximate support would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Three.js now has an example of area lights.  It is a very crude approximation (analytic  evaluation of the area integral after some serious simplification).  There is an article by Insomniac Games in GPU Pro 5 that offers are more accurate solution.

This only helps you with the area and shape of the light; you are on your own with the other attributes.

P.S. It's hard to tell from your question, but if your light format contains spectrum there have recently been some nice articles on real-time spectral lighting:

http://www.numb3r23.net/2013/03/26/spectral-rendering-on-the-gpu-now-with-bumps/